# Como solucionar o erro "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Quando eu tento executar o método `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Aluno")` da classe `Persistence` eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
run:
abr 04, 2016 9:11:30 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
abr 04, 2016 9:11:30 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
abr 04, 2016 9:11:30 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Aluno
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at hibernatetutorial.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Java Result: 1
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
```

Nesta mensagem:

> No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Aluno

Ele me diz que não há uma entidade chamada `Aluno`, entretanto, em minha unidade de persistência eu já defini a classe desta entidade. Já pesquisei a respeito, mas não encontrei a solução do problema.

Segue minha unidade de persistência:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="HibernateTutorialPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>hibernatetutorial.Aluno</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/escolabd?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="minhasenha"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Segue a estrutura do meu projeto:

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

Segue as bibliotecas que estou usando:

[image: bibliotecas]

A IDE que estou utilizando é o *NetBeans IDE 8.0.2*, e o Framework é o Hibernate.

Answer (score 3):

Segundo a documentação da classe [Persistence](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html) o método [createEntityManagerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory-java.lang.String-) recebe uma String que deve ser o nome do seu persistence unit. Pela configuração feita no seu persistence.xml você deve passar como parâmetro o nome `HibernateTutorialPU`

**Update:**
Para corrigir o erro `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/jandex/IndexView`basta você adicionar a seguinte dependência no `pom.xml`
Jandex é uma ferramenta que processa anotações Java dentro de um diretório ou arquivo jar, e salva os metadados dentro de um índice.

Se você estiver utilizando o Maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
  <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Passei o nome da minha unidade de persistência, mas, nao resolveu, deu outro tipo de erro veja: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/jandex/IndexView`.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver este problema? Estou tendo a mesma dificuldade, e fiz os passos acima mas não deu certo.